# can I install Ubuntu without a graphics card?

Tags: system-installation

can I install ubuntu on my PC currently running on windows 7 ultimate with 4gb ddr2 RAM intel pentium dual core e5300 2.6ghz no graphics card motherboard intel DG31PR ? **strong text**

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Answer (score 1):

A **dedicated GPU** (graphics card) is not needed for any version or flavor of Ubuntu, as long as your CPU has an integrated GPU and your motherboard supports it.  The majority of consumer CPUs and corresponding motherboards have integrated graphics capabilities.

You do not need a GPU at all if you want to install Ubuntu server, which does not contain a desktop environment, however you will likely need to run headless (without a display).

Comment: But my CPU is too Old it's intel Pentium dual core e5300 so can it run ubuntu desktop

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from downloading any of the versions of Ubuntu, like [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/downloads/) and trying it out for yourself.  You can "Try Ubuntu" from the installation media without installing.  When you're ready, generally, the installed system will run a bit faster than the live session.  If you get stuck, you can ask a new question.  If you need to ask again, please search and research before asking and share your research with us and be specific so we can effectively help.

Comment: thank you so much sir for your help